# Using c++ in iOS application(memory management)

Tags: c++, cocoa-touch, ios, memory-management

So... When you use C++ inside iOS app should you handle all the memory management by yourself or does it really matter? Sorry if this question is dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use C++ memory management for C++ objects; use Objective-C memory management for Objective-C objects. Basically, you need to manage all your memory somehow or other. What you do to free/delete/-release a block or object depends entirely on whether you malloc/new/-alloc to create it.

Comment: I meant that when you use C++, should you do like this
myClass * c1 = new myClass();

instead of

myClass c1;

Comment: Those are both C++ statements. Use the former if you want to instantiate the object dynamically, i.e. on the heap. Use the latter if it's a local object and you want it to be destroyed when it goes out of scope. Either way works if used appropriately, but the decision has nothing to do with Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about Objective C but in modern C++ you use smartpointers. You don't have to free or delete anything. All that is taken care of. Its as good as garbage collection but much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but it kind of is, you always have to manage your own memory in iOS apps unless you particularly don't care about using too much memory.

Comment: So when you are using c++ you should manually delete the objects right?

Comment: We're making an app with friend and he is writing a custom parser with C++ and he hasn't created objects to heap(used the new operator) instead he has done them like myObject c1; and let the computer handle the memory management. Could that be the reason why our app uses god damn 40mb ram on iOS

Comment: Maybe he's creating more objects than he needs to? Creating local objects shouldn't be a problem and that should be handled normally.

Comment: He has made a parser class which is singleton(I got one in my firstViewController). Should his class variables be like myClass * c1 = new myClass() instead of the normal way?

Comment: Well if he's only using them locally in a method then myClass c1(); should be fine, you could try using the Mac tool Instruments to check your memory allocations and find possible memory leaks.